# How to define the path where to install Python modules?

Tags: python, pip

On SUSE SLES 15.4, I recently installed Python 3.10, using the zypper package manager. I plan to install Airflow and some companion packages. I am confused about the way to install Python's stuff: how to avoid it to install in user's home folder?

I configured the following in **/etc/profile.d/python.sh**

```
# add python startup script for interactive sessions
export PYTHONSTARTUP=/etc/pythonstart
export AIRFLOW_HOME=/usr/lib/airflow
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3.10:$AIRFLOW_HOME
export LC_ALL="fr_CH.UTF-8"
export PATH=/usr/lib/airflow:/usr/lib/airflow/bin:/usr/lib:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/lib/airflow/bin:/usr/lib/airflow:/usr/lib/python3.10:/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I now own the **/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages** folder:

```
ls -al /usr/lib/python3.10
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 root      root         26  3 mai 16:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root      root       6414 12 jun 10:56 ..
drwxrwxr-x 1 a80838986 linuxusers  288 20 jun 10:34 site-packages
```

I try to install a Python package which is supposed to land in the site-packages folder:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting psycopg2-binary
  Using cached psycopg2_binary-2.9.6-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.0 MB)
Installing collected packages: psycopg2-binary
Successfully installed psycopg2-binary-2.9.6
```

but it finally ends in my home folder:

```
ls -al ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 a80838986 linuxusers 118 20 jun 10:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 a80838986 linuxusers  26 20 jun 10:32 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 a80838986 linuxusers 308 20 jun 10:32 psycopg2
drwxr-xr-x 1 a80838986 linuxusers 114 20 jun 10:32 psycopg2_binary-2.9.6.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x 1 a80838986 linuxusers 722 20 jun 10:32 psycopg2_binary.libs
```

So here are my questions:

1. How can I have **pip** to install - by default - the packages in the server's /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages?
2. Is /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages the right place?
3. How is it possible that **site-packages is not writeable** for pip?

Comment: Have you seen the `--target <dir>` ooption? With that, you can tell `pip` to isntall to any directory of your choosing. Just need to add it to PYTHONPATH

Comment: Yes, the -t option works fine for installing in the desired place. I am not familiar with Python, but I would have expected a convention to install modules by default into the right place: site-packages